# Using cURL in API where a Date Array is required

Tags: api, curl

I'm trying to create a simple cURL request to grab some JSON data and dump it into a file. Tried using command-line and PowerShell but can't 
figure out how to use a date array as required in the documentation (https://api.officevibe.com/docs/engagement)
The support at OfficeVibe is ridiculous, unless you know exactly what you're doing they're not very willing to help and any examples provided don't actually work (as i'm assuming they need to be part of a larger app).

Can anyone offer some advice on how i can get this working? (The Bearer ID isn't our actual ID)

Example from OfficeVibe which doesn't work in command-line or PowerShell:

c:\temp\curl.exe -k -X POST https://app.officevibe.com/api/v2/engagement  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"dates" : ["2019-04-01"]}' -o c:\temp\engagement.json

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was as easy - all i needed to do was add a backslash before the double-quote:

c:\temp\curl.exe -k -X POST https://app.officevibe.com/api/v2/engagement  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"dates\" : [\"2019-04-01\"]}'